# Values from system console

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

I have values printed in a system console in long lines and the lines are split to fit the window. 
Is there a way to copy the values without breaking the lines?
I'm using windows 10

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a blender-specific question? Seems to me this may be better suited to [super user](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an operating system console.

Comment: @gandalf3 I was hoping to get a solution maybe using python, but its simpler just to adjust the console window.

Comment: @Denis using python to manipulate the console/terminal would be even more platform specific. In linux you could for instance start blender in a pseudo terminal ([pty](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html)) and do whatever you want  .

Comment: @user2859 The question is not really about manipulating the console window, all I needed is a way to copy the values without breaking the lines.

Comment: Not sure how the windows 10 console works, but wrapping lines doesn't do anything bad for copy and paste in gnome-terminal. Then again windows console was always a mess. Or is it just about beautifying the output?

Comment: @user2859 If the lines are longer than the window they are split to the next line and I have to manually correct that, but adjusting the layout width fixing the problem like its shown in the answer.

Comment: @Denis Not really sure how it works on windows, but I doubt blender has any control over how the console decides to display output.

Comment: The minimum you could expect is usually 80x24, which is originated from the smallest [vt100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) resolution. That being said it's still not related to blender in any way. For instance the answer `gnome-terminal --geometry 80x24 -e ./blender` would also be correct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider changing the [width] property from the properties of your console.  You need to know the length of the longest line by inspection.

Under MS Windows it is done with the properties panel as depicted below.
Your OS was not specified.

Blender output seems wrapped to the current width of the console.

[image]

You can also consider changing your print statements to some some other function which writes text it to a file, append, open and close.  File Redirection may be possible.  I am not currently using Linux/Variants but in some programs one may choose the console.

Comment: Im on windows 10, and it solved the problem. where can i find an example how to print it into a text file? I have each frame printed into one line.

Comment: @Denis you can write the output directly to a file, no need to start blender with a pipe/redirection. `file=open('./myfile', 'w+')`
`file.write('Blah')` or even `print('Blah', file=file)`

Comment: Suppose you have N (number) print statements you want to go to a file.  You might copy and paste N new file write/append statements.  Depending on how much formatting you have you may or may not like this.  I suggest you have a new question if it is worth your time.  How do I convert/supplement Blender console Python print statements into file write/append statement in an efficient way?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger it doesnt really matter as long as I can copy the values correctly.

Comment: @user2859 Is a file close good form or unnecessary for append?   Name suggestion for windows myfile.txt.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger close is good form and recommended. The file will be automatically closed by the garbage collector though. I just left that out of the comment.